# Format time to show day and month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, formatting

For a project I am working on I receive date and time in this format:

```
2015-08-16 15:00:00 UTC 
yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss UTC
```

How can I make the time display as "Saturday, August 16th 2015 at 3:30PM"? ("15:00" would be fine as well.)

And how would I make it so it checks if the date has already passed or not, so that it only displays dates that have not passed?

Comment: For the formatting, have a look here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#strftime-method

Comment: You need to read through the documentation before asking. This is a pretty basic question and it's covered in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I make it so I can so that the time display as "Saturday, August 16th 2015 at 3:30PM (15:00 would be fine as well)?

```
Time.parse('2015-10-20 15:23 UTC').strftime('%A, %B %dth %Y at %l:%M%p')
#=> "Tuesday, October 20th 2015 at 3:23PM"
```

You might have to tweak it a bit to fix the suffixes (`1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, etc)

> And how would I make it so it checks if the date has already pasted or not?

You could do it like this (I'm sure there's a simpler way):

**EDIT**: Yes, there is a *much* simpler way -- check Matt's answer.

```
require 'time'

if Time.parse(my_date).to_i - Time.now.to_i > 0
  # my_date is in the future.
end
```

Comment: How would I convert "2015-08-16 15:00:00 UTC" into (2015,08,16,15,00,00,"-06:00") to run t = Time.new(2007,11,19,8,37,48,"-06:00") and the run Time.strftime

Comment: If I just use the with the format I have I get this: no implicit conversion of Time into String: d = Date._parse(date, comp)

Comment: This is my embedded ruby code: http://pastebin.com/JHu65dHc For some reason @date displays as nil when I puts it. When when I puts event.event_date I do get 2015-08-16 15:00:00 UTC. And when I put it in Time.parse(str) str=nil so it errors out. Why could this be?

Answer (score 1):

To start, convert your string to a `Time` object via `Time.parse(string)` ([APIDock](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/parse/class)).

After that you have all of the [Time](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html) class to play with.

```
time.strftime
time.past?
```

Comment: I can't find the class that displays the month. This is what I have so far: t.strftime("Event on %A at %I:%M%p | Time Zone: %:z")